# What is the Powershell syntax for adding and removing items from a TreelistEx field?

Tags: powershell-extensions

I want to edit some Placeholder settings with Powershell extensions, which involves adding a specific rendering to some and removing another rendering from others.

Is there a simple syntax based on the field type, or should I just use string replacement to edit the field?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use all Sitecore types to access and manipulate field value. 
Example

```powershell
# get your ph settings item
$phSettings = gi -path '/sitecore/layout/Placeholder Settings/content'

# read field and assign it to MultilistField type
[Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField]$field = $phSettings.Fields["Allowed Controls"]
```

Now you can read and set values

```powershell
# read IDs from an array of IDs
$field[0]

# replace ID inside an array
$phSettings.Editing.BeginEdit()
$field.Replace("{493B3A83-0FA7-4484-8FC9-4680991CF742}","{493B3A83-0FA7-4484-8FC9-4680991CF743}")
$phSettings.Editing.EndEdit()
```

`MultilistField` is an extension of `Sitecore.Data.Fields.DelimitedField` field type. Decompile it and see other methods available:

- `public int Count`
- `public string[] Items`
- `public bool Contains(string item)`
- `public string Add(string item)`
- `public string Remove(string item)`
- `public int IndexOf(string item)`